# Is there any way to pre-render a WebView control with Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, android, ios, .net, xamarin.forms

I've created a set of custom html5 audio controls which I'm using in my iOS and Android Xamarin Forms app.
When I navigate to the page in my app where this content is located, the WebView renders as a white box for a fraction of a second before it renders the html content. Is there any way to render this view before it is visible to the user?

```
public partial class TutorialPage : ContentPage
{
    private readonly ITutorialViewModel _dataModel;

    public TutorialPage(ITutorialViewModel dataModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Title = "Tutorial";
        var browser = new WebView() { HeightRequest = 150, WidthRequest = 400, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand };
        browser.Source = DependencyService.Get<IBaseUrl>().Get();
        mainStack.Children.Add(browser);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always use the events of the webview for that.

Take a look at them:

> Navigated - Event that is raised after navigation completes.
>
> Navigating - Event that is raised when navigation starts.

So what you have to do is set the webview's "IsVisible" property to false at the start, and when the Navigated event fires, set it back to true.

Example:

```
public partial class TutorialPage : ContentPage
{
    private readonly ITutorialViewModel _dataModel;

    private WebView browser;

    public TutorialPage(ITutorialViewModel dataModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Title = "Tutorial";
        browser = new WebView() { HeightRequest = 150, WidthRequest = 400, HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand, IsVisible = false };
        browser.Source = DependencyService.Get<IBaseUrl>().Get();
        browser.Navigated += Browser_Navigated:
        mainStack.Children.Add(browser);
    }

    void Browser_Navigated (object sender, WebNavigatedEventArgs e)
    {
        browser.IsVisible = true;
    }
}
```

If you don't want to make the WebView as a global class variable, you can get it from the sender parameter of the Navigated event, as shown below:

```
void Browser_Navigated (object sender, WebNavigatedEventArgs e)
{
    ((WebView)sender).IsVisible = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I bypassed my problem by making the background transparent. The controls still pop in but it's better than having a white box on the page in the meantime.